# Validating alphabetic only string in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I quickly validate if a string is alphabetic only, e.g

```
var str = "!";
alert(isLetter(str)); // false

var str = "a";
alert(isLetter(str)); // true
```

Edit : I would like to add parenthesis i.e `()` to an exception, so

```
var str = "(";
```

or

```
var str = ")";
```

should also return true.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Regular expression to require at least one letter, or paren, and only allow letters and paren:

```
function isAlphaOrParen(str) {
  return /^[a-zA-Z()]+$/.test(str);
}
```

Modify the regexp as needed:

- `/^[a-zA-Z()]*$/` - also returns true for an empty string
- `/^[a-zA-Z()]$/` - only returns true for single characters.
- `/^[a-zA-Z() ]+$/` - also allows spaces

Comment: `\s` and its cousins inside of character sets is not widely supported in other regular expression flavors, so I have a tendency to avoid it, although it will work fine in JavaScript.

Comment: The `i` flag may also be appropriate.

Comment: @Justin Johnson - Yup - `/^[a-z()]+$/i.test(str);` works too.

Comment: `/[A-z]/` includes a lot more characters than just letters in particular it would match `[ \ ] ^ _` and backtick (which is hard to type in a SO comment)

Answer (score 6):

Here you go:

```
function isLetter(s)
{
  return s.match("^[a-zA-Z\(\)]+$");    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If memory serves this should work in javascript:

```
function containsOnlyLettersOrParenthesis(str)
(
    return str.match(/^([a-z\(\)]+)$/i);
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use Regular Expressions...

<strike>functions isLetter(str) {
        return str.match("^[a-zA-Z()]+$");
    }</strike>

Oops... my bad... this is wrong... it should be

```
functions isLetter(str) {
    return "^[a-zA-Z()]+$".test(str);
}
```

As the other answer says... sorry